# Entity Framework fuzzy search on list of strings

Tags: string, list, entity-framework-core, fuzzy-search

EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.14

So i'm looking to implement a search where you can add multiple different elements to a search which will pull the relevant data from the DB (including lists of search params).

I'm fairly new to EF, but couldn't find anything on this..

The requirement is this:

1. if the list is empty - don't filter (there might be other search params)
2. if the list contains some strings, do a fuzzy search - i.e. string.Contains(string2)

it works in code - e.g.

```
            var list = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb" };
            var a = new List<string> { "a" };
            var c = new List<string> { "c" };
            var ab = list.Any(listString => a.Any(aString => listString.Contains(aString))); //returns true
            var ac = list.Any(listString => c.Any(cString => listString.Contains(cString))); //returns false
```

However, it doesn't work in entityframework.. i have tried using the below (only 1 of the lines in the WHERE at a time - result of the search is at the end of the row)

```
            var data = context.Meals
                .Where(x =>
                    (!descriptions.Any() || x.Ingredients.Any(db => descriptions.Any(input => input.Contains(db.Description))))  --FAIL
                    (!descriptions.Any() || x.Ingredients.Any(db => descriptions.Any(input => db.Description.Contains(input))))  --FAIL
                    (!descriptions.Any() || descriptions.Any(input => x.Ingredients.Any(db => db.Description.Contains(input))))  --FAIL
                    (!descriptions.Any() || descriptions.Any(input => x.Ingredients.Any(db => input.Contains(db.Description))))  --FAIL


                    (!descriptions.Any() || x.Ingredients.Any(db => db.Description.Contains(descriptions.First())))              --PASS - but restricted to using .First() 
                    (!descriptions.Any() || x.Ingredients.Any(db => descriptions.Contains(db.Description)))                      --PASS - but no fuzzy logic 
                    ).ToList();
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution - which is to loop through the list of strings outside EF and for each element, add a new where clause to the EF object..

However, this fix seems more like a workaround, than a proper implementation for using fuzzy search on 2 sets of strings

```
            var data = context.Meals;
            if(descriptions.Any()){
                descriptions.ForEach(input => data = data.Where(x => x.Any(db => db.Ingredient.Contains(input))))
            }
            return data.ToList();
```